# Autostart web page on login

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack

I've got a BBB with a LCD7 cape running debian 7.0 "wheezy", that I need to automatically open a web page on auto login. I don't have a    ~/.xinitrc    file. I've tried editing the    ~/.bashrc    file with
    'chromium-browser --kiosk http://example.com'
and
    'chromium-browser --start-fullscreen --app=/var/www/info.php'
I've also tried using openbox but with no success. I edited the    ~/.config/openbox/autostart.sh    When I open the terminal and type
    'openbox-session'
it says
    'Obt-Message: Xinerama extension is not present on the server'
    'Openbox-Message: A window manager is already running on screen 0'
What am I doing wrong..? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I got it solved.
`sudo nano /usr/share/xsessions/lightdm-xsession.desktop`
change the file to look like this:
`[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Openbox Session
Exec=openbox-session
Icon=
Type=Application`.
Then create a autorun file:
`sudo nano  ~/.config/openbox/autostart`
and add the following:
`chromium --kiosk http://www.website.yo.website`

Comment: Can't even get a vote for this.. Sucks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it solved. sudo nano `/usr/share/xsessions/lightdm-xsession.desktop` change the file to look like this:

> [Desktop Entry] Version=1.0 Name=Openbox Session Exec=openbox-session Icon= Type=Application.

Then create a autorun file: `sudo nano ~/.config/openbox/autostart` and add the following:

> chromium --kiosk http://www.website.yo.website